# i need a single function which replace func1,2,3,4,5 here

Tags: c, function, variables, struct, overriding

```
    struct setrate {
    int *rate;
    int numrate;
    }

/*func1 assigned lev1 by f1 */
    func1(struct setrate *name, int lev1, int f1)
    {
    name->rate[lev1] = f1;
    }

/*func1 assigned lev1 by f1 and lev2 by f2*/
    func2(struct setrate *name, int lev1, int f1, int lev2, int f2)
    {
    name->rate[lev1] = f1;
    name->rate[lev2] = f2;
    }
/*func1 assigned lev1 by f1 and lev2 by f2 lev3 by f3*/
    func3(struct setrate *name, int lev1, int f1, int lev2, int f2, int lev3, int f3)
    {
    name->rate[lev1] = f1;
    name->rate[lev2] = f2;
    name->rate[lev3] = f3;
    }
/* func4 and func5 */`enter code here`
    main()
    {
    struct setrate *name

    func1(name, 1, 10);
    func2(name, 1 10, 2, 20);
    func2(name, 1 10, 2, 20, 3, 30);
    func4()
    func5()
    }
```

Comment: Look up "c variadic functions"

Comment: `func2(name, 1, 10, 2, 20);` -> `func1(name, 1, 10); func1(name, 2, 20);` - now you only need 1 function

Answer (score 0):

Create a structure with two members:

```
struct st {
    int lev;
    int f;
};
```

and initialise this structure array with desired values and pass this array of structure along with the size of array to the function `funcx()` and in `funcx()`, iterate through the array and fill the `name` structure members.

There are several problems in your code, like missing `;`, missing `,` in function parameters etc. I am leaving these all up to you to to find out and fix. But I will point out a serious problem in your code - you code is accessing `name` pointer which is not pointing to any valid memory and this will lead to undefined behaviour.

You don't need to take `name` as pointer to `struct setrate` but need to allocate memory to `rate` member of `name` structure. Also, when you allocate memory dynamically you need to take care of free that memory once you done with it.

Putting these altogether, the implementation will be like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct setrate {
    int *rate;
    int numrate;
};

struct st {
    int lev;
    int f;
};

void print_val(struct setrate *p) {
    for (int i = 0; i < p->numrate; ++i) {
        printf ("%d ", (p->rate[i]));
    }
    printf ("\n");
}

void funcx (struct setrate *name, struct st *x, int x_sz) {
    for (int i = 0; i < x_sz; ++i) {
        name->rate[x[i].lev - 1] = x[i].f;
    }
    name->numrate = x_sz;
}

int main (void) {
    struct setrate name;

    name.rate = malloc (sizeof (int) * 3);
    if (name.rate == NULL) {
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct st x1[1] = {{1, 10}};
    funcx (&name, x1, sizeof(x1)/sizeof(*x1));
    print_val (&name);

    struct st x2[2] = {{1, 10}, {2, 20}};
    funcx (&name, x2, sizeof(x2)/sizeof(*x2));
    print_val (&name);

    struct st x3[3] = {{1, 10}, {2, 20}, {3, 30}};
    funcx (&name, x3, sizeof(x3)/sizeof(*x3));
    print_val (&name);

    free (name.rate);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out
10 
10 20 
10 20 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides variadic functions or macros, another option is using [compound literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) to pass the data in anonymous arrays. Sample code below, which also fixes the issues of uninitialized pointers in the posted code.

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct setrate {
    int *rate;
    int numrate;
} setrate;

void func(setrate *name, int n, int *p)
{
    for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        name->rate[k] = *p++;

#ifdef _DEBUG
    printf("n = %d: ", n);
    for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        printf(" %d", name->rate[k]);
    printf("\n");
#endif
}

int main()
{
    struct setrate name;
    name.rate = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));

    func(&name, 0, NULL);
    func(&name, 1, (int[]){11});
    func(&name, 2, (int[]){12, 22});
    func(&name, 3, (int[]){13, 23, 33});

    free(name.rate);
    return 0;
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/1KWMdj) with `_DEBUG` defined:

```
n = 0: 
n = 1:  11
n = 2:  12 22
n = 3:  13 23 33
```